# What song is played in Naruto Shippuden episode 21 Sasori Real Face at 11:30?

Tags: naruto, music

What song is played in Naruto Shippuden episode 21 Sasori's Real Face at 11:30 when Granny Chiyo sees Sasori's face. He replies "What's the matter Granny Chiyo are you so filled with emotion you can't speak?"

Answer (score 1):

I found it. It is called Sai's theme.

It's an unreleased OST in the naruto series

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted answer @AnimeFan2017